# Automapper not mapping my list properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

In my MVC5 project I use automapper to map my viewmodels to my models. But it seems that I'm doing something wrong, because not all my properties are mapped.

Here is my View Model

```
public class PlanboardViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Titel")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Omschrijving")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Verzoektype")]
    public int AbsenceTypeId { get; set; }

    public List<PlanboardEventMapViewModel> EventMap { get; set; }
    public List<PlanboardEventDetail> EventDetails { get; set; }
    public List<PlanboardRequest> PlanboardRequests { get; set; }

}
```

I use a separate class for my profiles:

```
public class PlanboardMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {

        //CreateMap<AbsenceType, AbsenceTypeViewModel>();
        //.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(s => !s.IsSourceValueNull));
        CreateMap<PlanboardViewModel, Planboard>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CSVHPlanboardEventDetail, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventDetails))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CSVHPlanboardEventMap, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventMap))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CSVHPlanboardRequest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PlanboardRequests));

        CreateMap<PlanboardEventMapViewModel, PlanboardEventMap>();
    }

}
```

In my repository I have the following code:

```
public int Create(PlanboardViewModel planboardViewModel)
{
        try {
            // map the viewmodel to the planboard model
            // Map the planboards to the view model
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<PlanboardMappingProfile>();
                cfg.CreateMap<PlanboardViewModel, Planboard>();
                cfg.CreateMap<PlanboardEventMapViewModel, PlanboardEventMap>();
            });

            IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            Planboard planboard = mapper.Map<Planboard>(planboardViewModel);
// Some more code here
```

When I submit the page and use the debugger, It shows that planboardViewModel has a list of values for PlanboardEventMapViewModel, PlanboardEventDetail, PlanboardRequest. The system is not telling me that there are any errors. When I check `planboard` after the mapping, it does not show any values for CSVHPlanboardEventDetail, CSVHPlanboardEventMap and CSVHPlanboardRequest. 
**EDIT**

My PlanboardModel is created DB First EF6:

```
public partial class Planboard
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Planboard()
    {
        this.CSVHPlanboardEventDetail = new HashSet<PlanboardEventDetail>();
        this.CSVHPlanboardEventMap = new HashSet<PlanboardEventMap>();
        this.CSVHPlanboardRequest = new HashSet<PlanboardRequest>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AbsenceTypeID { get; set; }

    public virtual AbsenceType AbsenceTypes { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PlanboardEventDetail> CSVHPlanboardEventDetail { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PlanboardEventMap> CSVHPlanboardEventMap { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PlanboardRequest> CSVHPlanboardRequest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show the Planboard model?

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu PlanboardModel is created with EF6 I've added the model to the question